# Update Many using Mongoose with condition

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying top update all documents in my MondoDB database using Mongoose. I know this question is asked many times but not in the way I need it answered. Im using version 4.2

Im trying to `updateMany` all documents in my collection is their `dueDate` is less then now. This call would chain off of every `.get` call.

**Example of a document:**

```
_id: ***************
reaccurance:
  Array0:
    "Daily"
status:
  Array0:
    "new"
dueDate: 2020-06-25T06:00:00.000+00:00
...
```

**Service.js**
This is what I've tried so far...Ive never used updateMany before and the documentation isn't very clear here.

```
 exports.setStatus = function(req, res) {
  Chore.updateMany({
    dueDate: { $gt: moment().format("X")},
  }, 
  {"$set": {"status": "pastDue"}}, function(err, chore) {
    if(err)
      res.send(err)
    res.json({
      message: 'Chores Updated Successfully',
      data: chore
    })
  });
}
```

The document prop `status` is an arrow of only 1 element of type string and current value of `new` the purpose of my call is to check every document and if its `dueDate` is past `now()` to updates its stats to `pastDue`

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.setStatus = function(req, res) {
  Chore.updateMany({
    dueDate: { $lt: moment()},
  }, 
  {
    "$set": {"status": "pastDue"}
  }, 
  function(err, chore) {
    if(err)
      res.send(err)
    res.json({
      message: 'Chores Updated Successfully',
      data: chore
    })
  });
}
```